# open pdf file automatically in folder

Tags: batch-file, pdf, automation, watch

I need to create a batch script which should act as a watch folder. Whenever a pdf file is landed in a specific folder it should get open automatically and if possible it should get delete on its own after two days exactly.

I tried this:

```
IF EXIST C:\TEMP\PDFbatch\*.pdf (
    CD C:\Temp\PDFBatch\
    for %%v in (*.pdf) do (
        "%%v"
        move "%%v" C:\TEMP\PDFbatch\Done\
    )
)
REM Delete files older than 2 days in Done folder
forfiles /p "C:\TEMP\PDFbatch\Done" /s /m *.pdf /D -2 /C "cmd /c del @PATH"
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: It is not working at all when I execute the script.. trying for alternative commands..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the following commented batch file:

```
@echo off
cd /D C:\Temp\PDFBatch

:ResetCount
set "WaitCount=0"

rem Search in set directory for *.pdf files (not directories) with
rem archive attribute set. For each PDF file having archive attribute
rem set, remove the archive attribute and open the PDF file by default
rem application for PDF files.

:OpenLoop
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir *.pdf /AA-D /B 2^>nul') do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\attrib.exe -a "%%I"
    start "" "%%I"
)

rem Wait 60 seconds before next loop run.
%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 60

rem After 3 hours (180 minutes) delete all PDF files older than 2 days.
set /A WaitCount+=1
if not %WaitCount% == 180 goto OpenLoop

rem Delete files older than 2 days in current folder.
%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /p "C:\Temp\PDFBatch" /m *.pdf /D -2 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /c del @PATH"
goto ResetCount
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `attrib /?`
- `cd /?`
- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `forfiles /?`
- `goto /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `start /?`
- `timeout /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.